# What am I doing wrong with this tuned oscillator?

Tags: oscillator, sine

How I can start it? I need a 27 kHz sine wave, but I can't run it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please consider providing references you are using as source material for this design and please also consider showing us your design thinking in getting to where you are. It would be appreciated.

Comment: Increase C3 it is Squegging

Comment: @Autistic That term takes me back a LONG time when grid effects would cause it. Is the term still used whenever self-quenching is observed like this?

Comment: NB: you certainly need "more" points in simulation ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this work, but some adjustments are necessary.
Not really sinusoidal for now ...

Made with [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/download.shtm).
Components adjusted with the interactive capabilities of the simulator.
Just point& click on components or "define" statements.
Then use "up" or "down" keys to change values.

[image]

Perhaps, something like this.

[image]

NB: all components seem to be involved in the wave "frequency" ... and "distortion".

Some "weird" pictures of this oscillator, stable and unstable.

[image]

[image]

Replacing the BJT with a current source (diode & IofI, beta) ...

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I found my mistake, it`s wrong polarity of secondary coil. 
I'm very angry at multisim because the polarity is not indicated in it as in your program. Also i would like to ask you how did you choose the values of C1,C3,R3,R5. What is the name of the program you used to design the circuit?

Comment: Added link in the answer. NB: you probably can change the "shape" of the device and add "+". Please also note that the conditions of oscillations are very "difficult" in this circuit. I had to interactively search for the "influence" of all components for sinusoidal outputs. Used the (x,y) functions for seeing.  I add also in answer. Will try to find "transfer function" later.